# RTF vs Python and “section break”

Tags: python-3.x, rtf

Good day to all! I need your help! There is an RTF file in which the first line is a "section break" because of what my code does not work

```
import pyperclip
import os
from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text

rtf = open('01-08.2020.rtf').read()
text = rtf_to_text(rtf)
a = text.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('cp1251')
i = a.find('Поступ.')
if i != -1:
    a = a[:i]
pyperclip.copy(a)
```

and an error occurs

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 34-35: ordinal not in range(256)
```

if preliminarily launches the file in MS Word and removes the “section break” then the program works ideally. I will be glad of any help! Thank!

Comment: You can probably scan `text` and remove all the characters that can't be encoded in ISO 8859-1 before you try to encode it.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @DennisSparrow Thank you for your interest! What do you mean by the word "scan"? The idea is to minimize the operator’s actions as there are a lot of files and each one cannot be opened in MS Word to work out unfortunately. P.S. I'm still a beginner! Is there functionality in python for scanning rtf documents to remove non-text code?

Comment: The `rtf_to_text` function you are calling gives you a Python string, which uses Unicode character encoding.  Unicode can use more than one byte to represent a character, but ISO 8859-1 uses only one byte per character.  The section break apparently involves one or more characters that don't fit in the ISO 8859-1 encoding.  When you get a text string derived from RTF, your script can examine each character in the string ("scan") and remove those that don't fit in ISO 8859-1 encoding.  Then you won't get the error, but you may lose some information.